# Postgres : Table partitionated and Normal Table, Without conditional, which one is faster?

Tags: postgresql

in Postgres I have a table partitioned by date, I know that internally when I perform a search by range by specific date, Postgres will only analyze the partitions that are from that range.

But what happens if I no longer search by date but by another column such as an id, would it be the same as a seq scan as a normal table?

and I have another question:
If I have two tables with the same information in both

```
Normal table : users
Partition table: users_partitioned
```

At the performance level, which would be faster?

1. select * from users
2. select * from users_partitioned

my intention is to know if the partitioned tables search in parallel in the partitions, and thus the response speed can be improved

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: I already did it, and that is precisely what confuses me, although the query schedule is a tree, the nodes are executed in parallel?

Comment: If the plan doesn't say they are parallel, then they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query on the partitioned table will be slightly slower, because both the optimizer and the executor have more work to do. The overhead should increase linearly with the number of partitions.

No parallelism will be used, because rows found by parallel workers would have to be gathered at the parallel leader process, and that overhead would render a parallel plan inefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and in the cases of the indexes? the speed would be the same as the normal table? or with partitioned tables it will be slower, consider that it will be indexes that will have columns such as an ID, and I will not use a date range

Comment: There are no indexes on your table... can you be a bit more specific? What would the index and the query look like?

Comment: I meant that I have an index in my partitioned table, that index was created based on an ID column, what happens if I query the partitioned table by id? Postgres would have to search all partitions by index?
Note: my partitioned table is created by date range

Comment: Then that query will also be slower on the partitioned table. Possibly only a little bit, but with a fast query with an index scan that could be significant.

Comment: thank you very much, now that I know how it works, if I want to apply partition tables, I must always make sure that my queries to that table are always searched by a range, so that postgres only searches in the partitions of that range, if I did not use by range I would not have sense to apply partitioned tables, is it correct?

Comment: @Reaper_20 Not necessarily. There are other advantages to partitioning besides performance gains. In my opinion, the biggest advantage of partitioning is getting rid of old data by dropping a partition.